# how to find closest spritenode to the bottom of scene in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a function that creates falling skspritenodes. The function makes a skspritenode that an action moves to the bottom and then removes. It is called every second. I am trying to create a new function that would find the lowest of these skspritenodes at a given time. I have tried to use enumeratechildnodes(withname:) since all of these skspritenodes have the same name, and then I append their position.y to an array. I then check if the skspritenode position.y is equal to the min value of the array of Ints. If yes then it would be the lowest.

```
func searchLowest() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ball") {node,_ in
        let sprite = node as! SKSpriteNode

            var distanceArray = [Int]()

                let distance = Int(sprite.position.y)
                distanceArray.append(distance)

                let spritePosition = Int(sprite.position.y)

                if spritePosition == distanceArray.min {
                ...
                }
    }
}
```

but then I get this error message:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and
>   '() -> Int?'

I am new to `SpriteKit` and any advice would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure is executed for each node that matches but your code storing the array is inside the closure so distanceArray contains only one element every execution and every element is the closest one during the closure.

Also, you have a syntax error calling min where you're not actually calling the function.  Needs parens.

This may not be the best way to find the closest ball, but here is a modification of your code I think works:

```
var distanceArray = [Int]()
var closestNode : SKSpriteNode?
scene.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ball") {node,_ in

    if let sprite = node as? SKSpriteNode {
        let distance = Int(sprite.position.y)
        distanceArray.append(distance)
        if distance == distanceArray.min() {
            closestNode = sprite
        }
    }
}
print ("\(String.init(describing: closestNode))")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your syntax is flawed. You want to call `Array.min()` and not `Array.min`, which due to the trailing closure (that you use for the `if` statement) the compiler infers as the function `Array.min(by:)`, hence the error about comparing an `Int` to a closure of type `()->Int?`. You just simply have to call `distanceArray.min()` to fix the issue.

However, there seems to be a bigger problem with your current code. `distanceArray` should be declared outside the enumeration scope, otherwise it will always have only a single element, the distance of the current node. Moreover, you probably want to check if the distance is smaller than or equal to the current minimum rather than to check if it's equal to the minimum. There's also no need to declare `position` as you already store the exact same value in `distance`.

```
func searchLowest() {
    var distanceArray = [Int]()
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ball") {node,_ in
        let sprite = node as! SKSpriteNode
        let distance = Int(sprite.position.y)
        distanceArray.append(distance)

        if let currentMin = distanceArray.min(), distance <= currentMin {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```